# I want to refresh recycle adapter where data is coming from Firebase?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

I have ArrayList I am setting data to adapter successfully I want to add swipe to refresh t the adapter to check any new data available in firebase to update recycler.

```
    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    getFirebaseData();

}

public void getFirebaseData()
{
    databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("recyclerview");
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) 
        {
            itemsModel=new ItemsModel();
            itemsModel=dataSnapshot.getValue(ItemsModel.class);
            itemsModelList.add(itemsModel);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at the RecyclerView.Adapter official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter). There are methods notifyItemInserted, notifyItemChanged etc as per the action you intend to perform. There is also a DiffUtil method to update the recyclerview with least amount of changes and animations if the dataset is changed. Read [this](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00).

Comment: Check out below link. It will help you to achieve what you want.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299903/how-to-know-which-exactly-new-entry-is-added-in-firebase-db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only call once : recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter) on the OnCreate method.

Then, when a child will be added, as you as listening to your ref in the db, the method onChildadded will be called and you use this code inside it :

```
itemsModel=new ItemsModel();
        itemsModel=dataSnapshot.getValue(ItemsModel.class);
        itemsModelList.add(itemsModel);
        myAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Then, everytime a child is added, it will be displayed in your screen.

Comment: * you don't need to refresh the data as your are constantly listening to it.